# Change pseudo element color on selected state

Tags: less

I want to change arrow color as well as circle when click on it. I am using LESS and getting right place to add `border-top-color: #0066ff;` Can anyone suggest please? Here is code:

LESS:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 225px;
    height:225px;
    border: 6px solid #ff6600;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    &.selected {
        border: 6px solid #0066ff;
    }
    &:after {
        top: 104%;
        left: 50%;
        border: solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
        border-top-color: #ff6600;
        border-width: 10px;
        margin-left: -10px;
        transform: scaleY(1.6);
        &.selected {
            border-top-color: #0066ff;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.circle').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

JS fiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/kunjsharma/6eu431hp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `:after` inside `.selected`: [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8h2cdoz5/)

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 225px;
    height:225px;
    border: 6px solid #ff6600;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    &.selected {
        border: 6px solid #0066ff;
        &:after { // <-- moved this inside .selected
            border-top-color: #0066ff;
        }
    }
    // rest of the styles...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hooman, thanks for reply. I've edited my fiddle with cdn paths.

Comment: @jnuK: I was to quick to reply... I have updated the answer with the fiddle that does what you want...

Comment: Great, thanks! Meanwhile, I find one more solution: `&.selected :after { border-top-color: #0066ff; }` inside `.circle`.

Comment: @jnuK - cool, though that solution is the same as my answer! ;-)